# gitlab: git clone https with large repos fails

Tags: git, git-clone, gitlab

When trying to clone a large repo (~700MB) over https, git fails with:

```
c:\git-projects>git clone https://git.mycompany.de/fs.git
Cloning into 'fs'...
Username for 'https://git.mycompany.de': mwlo
Password for 'https://mwlo@git.mycompany.de':
efrror: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

clone over ssh works:

```
c:\git-projects>git clone git@git.mycompany.de:fs.git
Cloning into 'fs'...
remote: Counting objects: 144564, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30842/30842), done.
remote: Total 144564 (delta 95360), reused 143746 (delta 94542)
Receiving objects: 100% (144564/144564), 601.34 MiB | 1.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (95360/95360), done.
Checking out files: 100% (4649/4649), done.
```

Cloning smaller repositories with https also works:

```
c:\git-projects>git clone https://git.mycompany.de/git-test.git
Cloning into 'git-test'...
remote: Counting objects: 135, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (129/129), done.
remote: Total 135 (delta 68), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (135/135), 18.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (68/68), done.
```

I have already tweaked some parameters but without success:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes  2; # have two cpu's
keepalive_timeout  120;
client_max_body_size 3072m;

/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml
## Git settings
  # CAUTION!
  # Use the default values unless you really know what you are doing
  git:
    bin_path: /usr/bin/git
    # Max size of a git object (e.g. a commit), in bytes
    # This value can be increased if you have very large commits
    max_size: 3221225472 # 3072.megabytes
    # Git timeout to read a commit, in seconds
    timeout: 120
```

We would like to use git clone https, as the visual studio tools for git still not have implemented ssh.

On the server are two processes, CPU load goes to 100% after a while, then the processes are terminated.

```
git pack-objects --revs --all --stdout --progress --delta-base-offset
```

Regards, Marco

---

```
System information
System:         Debian 6.0.7
Current User:   root
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p392
Gem Version:    1.8.23
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.0.4

GitLab information
Version:        5.3.0
Revision:       148eade
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            https://git.mycompany.de
HTTP Clone URL: https://git.mycompany.de/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git.mycompany.de:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        1.4.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Terminated by what? oom-killer? ulimit? Something else?

Comment: what is the size of your tmp area and the RAM ?

Comment: tmp is 2GB, ulimit is unlimited, no killed process in syslog

Answer (score 5):

This is reported in [issue 3079](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3079): https cloning requires a large amount of resources (CPU, but mainly memory) on the GitLab server, and currently (GitLab 5.x) large repos.

Even GitLab 6.0 comes with [commits like 7ecebdd](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/7ecebdd02df9b11fa6ba4f8033dcfe097935ed66), mentioning timeouts when cloning *large* repo.

I haven't tested with GitLab 6, though (which should release tomorrow).

Comment: I will update to 6.0 these days, let's see if it brings a fix.

Comment: 6.0.1 having the same issues. Now it runs with unicorn not puma and error code is 502.

Comment: @mawl I have seen that switch (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398991/6309). But I didn't see a 6.0.1. I follow the commits for the upcoming 6.1.

Comment: Version 6.0 is 6.0.1 (Take a look on the help page after updating)

Comment: @Vonc, Im having the same issue in 6.2.3. How do we resolve this ?

Comment: @maestromani did you try with a more recent version of GitLab first?

Comment: @Vonc, Since this is a production server need to plan that activity :-(. If i didn't get any solution then i have too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a chunking plugin for nginx, such as [HttpChunkinModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule).

I personally haven't deployed the above but have a client with similar issues.

In their case, the problem is on the client side, where we need to instruct devs to use the following tweak to their local git config:

git config http.postBuffer 524288000 #Set to 500MB

The above will simply allow larger git-related http requests on the client side (we've got plenty of memory on the server side).

Comment: The HttpChunkinModule is no longer needed if you are using nginx > 1.3.8 http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule

Comment: I had the same error when pushing to a https server, this fix solved the problem, thanks.