# WebMatrix 3, cannot push on GitLab

Tags: git, webmatrix, gitlab

I registered myself and a created a new private project on Gitlab. After that, I installed a git client on my Windows 7 PC and I followed the command line instructions on Gitlab to create my new local repository:

```
git config --global user.name "myname"
git config --global user.email "myemail"
```

Create Repository:

```
mkdir myprojdir
cd myprojdir
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/myusername/myprojectname.git

git push -u origin master
```

Now when I open WebMatrix3, I open the empty remote source control site:

```
https://gitlab.com/myusername/myprojectname.git
```

I copy my files to the local directory indexed by git, I commit to local git, and finally I push to Gitlab.

At this point WebMatrix reports this error:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
Everything up-to-date
git error code 1.

   in 

    GitSCCProvider.GitCommandLine.GitProcessRunInvoked(GitProcessTracker gitProcessTracker)
   in 

    GitSCCProvider.GitCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GitAsyncCommandLineExecute>b__0()
   in 

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   in 

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this stackoverflow thread:

[gitlab: git clone https with large repos fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826660/gitlab-git-clone-https-with-large-repos-fails)

I tried to add to my Webmatrix project a small amount of files (I tried with less than 1,3MB of total size) at a time, commit locally and push to Gitlab, repeating until all files and folders where into the project.
By this way I manage to clone my project on Gitlab.