# GIT push, HTTP code = 502 error

Tags: git, gitlab

My project size is 1,63 GB (Magento Project)
I had followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7p0hrpNaJ14)

when I do this command : `git push -u origin master` , it is starting to write objects and after that I getting this error in git console:

```
error: RPC failed, result=22, HTTP code = 502
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What should I do to make this work ?

The result of the git remote -v is :
[image]

Comment: How is the git repository hosted? Locally, GitHub, GitLab...? Do you host it yourself, or use some hosting provider? Is there a proxy in front of the repository server?

Comment: And incidentally, a repo size of >1GB is pushing git's limits. Consider using something like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).

Comment: @sleske I m using a hosting provider

Comment: @Chester: And which one would that be? And with which access method?

Comment: i have to install git-annex ? it will work 100% ?

Comment: @Chester: You don't have to, but it will avoid some problems. However, you will need some extra setup (and a separate provider for file storage). If you are interested, read up on git-annex, then if you still have a question, ask it separately.

Comment: @Chester: 502 is "Bad gateway". It usually means that the web server (nginx, Apache...) in front of the actual service is telling you that that service is not running - not accepting requests. Usually it cannot start due to configuration error, wrong configuration, missing dependencies... We need to know more details to what are you actually connecting. What does `git remote -v` print out?

Comment: @Messa I updated my post , please check it out

Comment: Is it possible to use SSH instead of HTTP? The URL should be then `ssh://netlogiq@gitlab.netlogiq.eu:2112/attin/test.git`. I've found some info about problems with pushing large commits (or possibly large amount of commits?) to Gitlab, for example https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3882 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826660/gitlab-git-clone-https-with-large-repos-fails

Comment: @Messa I certanly sure that I used HTTP :)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether HTTP or HTTPS. The problem is that it has to go through web server, which adds another layer of timeouts and max size limits.

Comment: Does your project need to be that large? Are you storing videos in the repository? Of course you can use it however you want, but it will be a lot less painful if your are only managing source code and not binary files. There are ways to find large blogs in your repository and remove them.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/error%3A+RPC+failed+result%3D22+-+Push+to+Stash+fails

check this out, it can be useful

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The remote end hangs up because the pack size you are trying to transmit exceeds the maximum HTTP post size. Try to limit this pack size with

```
git config --local http.postBuffer 157286400
```

to 150MB.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  I was using a standard / default Git installation.

Comment: This solution still working. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 12):

I got this problem when I had proxy set, but actually did not need proxy.

To fix:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue after I added HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to make other things work. I was unable to use our internal git repos. There is a way to fix it to fix it:
You can add proxy variables with empty values to git using `git config --global --edit`:

```
[http]
    proxy = 
[https]
    proxy =
```

Or using commands:

```
git config --global --add http.proxy ""
git config --global --add https.proxy ""
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below commands.

git config --global user.name "dummy"

git config --global user.email "dummy@g.com"

git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

for more information : https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/error-rpc-failed-result-22-push-to-stash-fails-604537633.html

Answer (score 2):

first increase size

```
# git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000                                   
git config --global http.postBuffer 500M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M
git config --global core.compression 0
```

to check size

```
git config --get http.postBuffer
```

then open server terminal

```
su
nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb 

#edit this line
unicorn['worker_timeout'] = '4000'

#running
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

#for any case restart machine

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I switched from proxy connection (via CNTLM) to direct.
The solution is to remove this line from http section in file c:\Users\.gitconfig:

```
proxy = localhost:3128
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got the same error (HTTP 502 Bad gateway curl 22) when I created a git repository on a server under `root` user. Of course in this situation fcgiwrap and git-http-backend couldn't receive data from a client under `www-data` user. So after re-initialization of a server repository under `www-data` user the error is gone. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I think this is my problem but I don't see or don't know how to find this user. Could you supply the steps that you did so that I can try to see if this helps me?

Comment: Thank you! `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data .` on the server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error and none of these solutions worked.  It was a stupid mistake but I thought I would add it in case anyone else runs into it.  I forgot the ".git" on the end of the URL when setting the remote origin.

Comment: Worked for me!.Needed to add ".git" to config file under the [remote "origin"] url section

Answer (score 0):

if you are experiencing this issue on source tree , then do the following :

1. Open preferences ( on Mac ) or settings ( in windows )
2. click on 'Git' tab.
3. Find "git version". under git version click on 'reset to Embedded git' button and then click back on 'Use System Git' button. ( this setting is for Mac OS , if you are using windows , find something similar there. ) [image]

see image

Answer (score 0):

My `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` were setup in environment variable(s) for one project. So, removing this from environment variable(s) helped me sort the issue.